# Key pressed + gotoAndPlay(xy) Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a flash game with 2 animation. A standing animation and a moving animation. I want that if someone press up-down-left-right arrow then play moving animation, and if these keys aren't pressed then play standing animation.

I used:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movingAnimation);
function movingAnimation(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("moving");
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("moving");
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("moving");

    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("moving");
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, standingAnimation);

function standingAnimation(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("standing");
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("standing");
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("standing");

    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
            account_animation.gotoAndPlay("standing");
    }
}
```

This is not working. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: this code is on your timeline i take it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is nothing wrong with your code. You should verify a few things:

- Click on your swf when it's being previewed ( perhaps you are not selected in that window so the keyboard events are not firing. )
- Make sure the animation frame labels are correct.
- Check that `account_animation` is the correct asset to be doing the gotoAndPlay on.

I tested your code to verify that it is working properly, so you'll need to verify your asset and timeline setup to make sure all of that is correct since we cannot see your timeline in your fla file.